# Visual Studio 2017 expects extra underscore in function names

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, static-libraries, linker-errors, static-linking

I have a static library from a 3rd party and the header. The functions are declared as `extern "C"` in the header and they are exported in the library - I checked with `dumpbin /exports library.lib`.

When trying to use the library I included the header and added the library to Linker->Input. The code compiles, but it doesn't link because the linker expects an extra underscore for the functions defined in the library. For example if in the header I have:

```
extern "C"
{
    int serialInit();
}
```

`dumpbin` shows me:

```
Exports
   ordinal    name
         6    serialInit
```

and the linker gives me:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _serialInit referenced in function _main
```

Do you know why Visual Studio expects the extra underscore in the function name? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You do link with the library?

Comment: Missing #pragma comment(lib, "library.lib") ?

Comment: I added the library to Linker->Input, `#pragma comment(lib, "library.lib") ` shouldn't be necessary, but I've tried with it - same problem

Comment: @KennyOstrom - adding `#include "staticLib.h"` in the "minimal example" `staticLib.cpp` file fixed it. I removed the example as it doesn't reproduce the original problem

Comment: what function linkage are you using? a leading underscore indicates [cdecl usually...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx)

Comment: The leading underscore is standard *identifier decoration* in 32-bit code.  It helps the linker recognize calling convention mismatches.  This is a `__cdecl` function, nothing special.  The dumpbin output is for a DLL, not a static library, probably has something to do with the linker error.  Not enough bread crumbs.  Use a telephone, talk to the library owner.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, the problem was with a 32bit version vs 64 bit version of the lib. Can you please turn your comment into an answer?